# Get image url via xml in php

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

**php code:**

```
  <?php 

        $url = 'https://www.rudolphs-christmasshop.com.au/api/v2/products/'; 
        $username ='xyz'; $password ='ca25fe6947564b9479sdfsaffsaffasfasfsaffdasfe5866b4'; 
        $ch = curl_init(); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD,$username . ':' . $password); 
        $result = curl_exec($ch); curl_close($ch); 
        $xml = simplexml_load_string($result); 

    ?>
```

output

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
    [product] => Array ( 
        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
            [id] => 29 
            [name] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) 
            [type] => physical 
            [sku] => 22254 
            [description] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) 
            [search_keywords] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) 
            [availability_description] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) 
            [price] => 22.9500 
            [inventory_warning_level] => 5 
            [warranty] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) 
            [weight] => 0.2500 
            [width] => 13.0000 
            [height] => 11.0000 
            [depth] => 8.0000 
            [view_count] => 125 
            [page_title] => Aussie Koala and Baby Christmas Ornament - Australiana 
            [meta_keywords] => koala bear decoration, koala christmas ornament, australian decorations, aussie christmas, christmas decoration 
            [meta_description] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) 
            [layout_file] => product.html 
            [is_price_hidden] => false 
            [price_hidden_label] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) 
            [categories] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
                [value] => 30
            ) 
            [downloads] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
                [link] => /products/29/downloads ) 
                [images] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
                    [link] => /products/29/images 
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

How could I get the image url and display image on browser

Answer (score 1):

May be wrong but I guess like this if I look [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php)

`echo $xml->product[0]->downloads->images->link;`

But if you show us your XML we are more able to help you.

Greets

Answer (score 1):

I can't test it here. But you can access the tree with:

if you have more products:

```
<?php
foreach($xml->product as $pout ) {
    echo $pout->downloads->images->link;
}
?>
```

if you want only one product something like this:

```
$xml->product[0]->downloads->images->link;
```